# I would like to create an addon for a custom cube

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I would like to create an addon that has some fields on the UI panel to enter the XYZ coordinates to create a custom cube. Is there a simple way to do this without go crazy with code?

For now I have this:

```
import bpy

#here I would like to create fields for panel and link with these variables
x = bpy.context.object.scale[0] = #customvalue X typed by user
y = bpy.context.object.scale[1] = #customvalue Y typed by user
z = bpy.context.object.scale[2] = #customvalue Z typed by user


#Then I want to create a button on panel named GENERATE or CREATE, for returns result of typed values
print(bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(x, y, z)))
```

Im so sorry for my beginner english and code knowledges.
And Thank you a lot for the help!

Comment: you should first search for addon structure(there are good videos on the net). your main goal is simple. once you feel comfortable with that concept and structure you can simply implement it.

Comment: Take a look at [Scripting for Artists](https://studio.blender.org/training/scripting-for-artists) starting at Video 08 _Your own Operator_ and then do 09, 10 and maybe 11.  That will give you the basics you need to create an addon, as well as an example with input data and a panel.